# Accessing and assigning values in each part of the struct in an "array" of structs?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I have an assignment to allocate enough memory to store a set of structs with different values in them. I am only allowed to call malloc once.

A have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct ObjectTag Object;
struct ObjectTag
{
    char *stringA[20];
    char *stringB[30];
    char *stringC[5];
    unsigned short num;
};
```

For my malloc call I am doing

```
Object *myObjArray;
myObjArray= (Object*)malloc(numObjects * sizeof(Object));
```

I am trying to get information from an infile to place into my structs. Thus I am doing

```
fscanf(inFile, " %s", (*Object)[i].stringA);
fscanf(inFile, " %s", (*Object)[i].stringB);
fscanf(inFile, " %s", (*Object)[i].stringC);
fscanf(inFile, " %hu", (*Object)[i].num);
```

and so on in a loop.

But when I try to compile I get this error

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char **'
```

and also this for the last one

```
format '%hu' expects argument of type 'short unsigned int *', but argument 3 has type 'int'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Notes that may be relevant:

- The infile has an expected format to it
- I have counted how many structs I needed as noted by the numObjects in the malloc call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *stringA[20]` is NOT a string of 20 (or 19) characters.  It is **an array of 20 strings of unspecified length**.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, do you know why the second error is still happening though? The %hu one.

Comment: Because to input a number (whether it is int, short, long, float, double etc.) you should give its address to fscanf, like  `int foo; fscanf("%d", &foo);`  It is because no function can change the value of its argument.

Comment: Doh that makes so much sense. Sorry to bother with the lame question.